# Bootstrap 4.6 grid system/Flexbox not being restricted by parent element height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm having a terribly difficult time trying to get Bootstrap/Flexbox to play nice with a height restriction.

In my layout, I have a `<main>` element with a fixed height. In the actual app it's calculated so that the footer appears at the bottom of the screen, for demonstration it's fixed at 500px.

I want to put some arbitrary-length user data (between 1 and potentially up to 1000 lines according to API response) in a card. I would like the card to be constrained by the calculated height of its container, with a scrollbar *in the card* to navigate its contents. However, the `card-body` seems absolutely totally intent on just growing to contain all contents - I can't get any part of the hierarchy to be limited by the 500px height set on the `<main>` element.

Here's a simplified example. The dark bar is the footer, which is correctly positioned below the 500px `<main>` element. The card stretches waaaaay past it - I want the card to be contained between the top of the page and the footer, and have a scrollbar to navigate its contents.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Manage List</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main style="height: 500px">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Your Items</div>
                            <div class="card-body overflow-auto">
                                    dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="py-4 bg-dark"></footer>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Related questions I have looked at:
[When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width#)
[Prevent flex item from exceeding parent height and make scroll bar work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487743/prevent-flex-item-from-exceeding-parent-height-and-make-scroll-bar-work)
[Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)
[white-space css property is creating issues with flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897730/white-space-css-property-is-creating-issues-with-flex)
[Fitting child into parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826555/fitting-child-into-parent)
[Flex item is not shrinking smaller than its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456839/flex-item-is-not-shrinking-smaller-than-its-content)

I have tried `min-height: 0` everywhere, `flex-shrink: 1`, `flex-grow: 0`, and other suggestions from the above questions. Really at a loss for what to do next short of pinning the height of every single element down the hierarchy with `height: 100%` to make sure it doesn't grow past `<main>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the container `h-100 d-flex flex-column`, and then `h-100` on column and card. Use `overflow-hidden` on the row so its height is contained by the container.

```
<main style="height: 500px">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row overflow-hidden">
            <div class="col-7 h-100">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-header">Your Items</div>
                    <div class="card-body overflow-auto"> dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer class="py-4 bg-dark"></footer>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/DdmfcnJ6hH)

Answer (score 1):

You have to work your way down the stack, applying d-flex, h-100, and flex-column as you go to get things to fit within their parent container.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<main style="height: 500px">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex overflow-hidden">
            <div class="col-7 h-100">
                <div class="card d-flex flex-column h-100">
                    <div class="card-header">Your Items</div>
                    <div class="card-body overflow-auto">
                            dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer class="py-4 bg-dark"></footer>
```

Comment: This seems effectively identical to my proposed and unwanted solution of pinning everything down the hierarchy (there's more than what's in this example) with `h-100`. It works, but it seems excessive... if this is just the way to do it though then there's nothing else to it.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to set `height` or `max-height` on `.card-body`.
Below, I calculate the height of `<main>` and the `.card-body` based on the viewport.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Manage List</title>
  <style>
    main {
      padding-bottom: 1em;
      /* viewport height minus footer height  */
      height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    }
    
    main .card .card-body {
      /* viewport height minus footer height minus height of preceeding elements minus main padding-bottom */
      height: calc(100vh - 48px - 7em - 1em);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main style="">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Your Items</div>
            <div class="card-body overflow-auto">
              dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>dsfg<br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="py-4 bg-dark"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I thought about this, but this means I'll have to figure out how to calculate the height for each card... which seems like a somewhat inelegant solution. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'd usually want solutions to problems like these to be generic, so I can apply them to all problems of this type going forward. Manually calculating the height for the card in this situation means in the future if I have more complex layouts or just two cards on top of each other for example, I'd have to figure out how to calculate it for each. It's a working solution but inelegant.